# Icon not showing on iPad 2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I've named the icons correctly, added them in the project, they show up fine in simulator and iPad 1G but not just on iPad 2, tried everything but it still displays a blank white icon for the app.

Comment: Nimbuz, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem. The icon shows up in the simulator, but not on the actual iPad2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following format for iPad icon files:

```
filename-ipad.png
```

and in your case it should be

```
icon-ipad.png
```

Comment: But in the documentation, those names have been mentioned that I have used? Also, its universal app, not iPad-only.

Comment: Right also mentioned in Apple Documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: please check your icon size As suggested by @Heart PAL

Comment: Let me see - icon@2x.png is 114x114; icon.png is 57x57; icon-72.png is 72x72 - verified in photoshop.

Comment: And supposing that icon size is incorrect, why would it show fine on simulator and ipad 1g, but not ipad 2?

Comment: @Nimbuz : Could you try by adding ipad text in icon image name just try once let's see the result ...

Comment: The strange thing is, the icon shows fine in the multitasking bar (that comes up on double-tap home button), but not on the homescreen.

Comment: We had the same problem (icon showed only in multitasking bar), solved by renaming the icon to exactly Icon-72.png

Comment: Not the answer, nor helpful, but still choosing it to close.

Answer (score 0):

it happens .when Your icon size is not proper . please check your icon size .

Or please see this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: Remove all setting and set icon-ipad.png nameed image in resource .

Answer (score 0):

Had this strange issue with icon-72.png not showing up in iPad non-retina simulator.
everything was in place. Iconfiles keys in plist also set.
Just changed the device from non-retina to retina..it shows up.. switched back to normal device...shows up there as well.. Had no clue wat was the problem and why it got resolved like this..